# How to specify web service client security policy in weblogic?

Tags: weblogic, webservice-client, security-policy

I am building a web service client deployed in Weblogic 12c as part of a web application. The web service that I am trying to consume has the following security policy:

- wss11_saml_or_username_token_with_message_protection_service_policy

As I read [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E14571_01/web.1111/b32511/policies.htm), in this case a web service client must use either of the following two policies:

- oracle/wss11_saml_token_with_message_protection_client_policy
- oracle/wss11_username_token_with_message_protection_client_policy

So far I have downloaded and installed all certificates in the certificate chain in the trust keystore of my weblogic server.
I generated a web service client using Netbeans (using JAX-WS RI 2.2.6-1b01).
I set up username and password as follows:

```
Map<String, Object> rc = ((BindingProvider) port).getRequestContext();
rc.put(BindingProvider.USERNAME_PROPERTY, "username");
rc.put(BindingProvider.PASSWORD_PROPERTY, "password");
```

And I invoked one of the web service operations.

Unfortunately, I am getting an error at runtime involving a NullPointerException when trying to use the SAML credentials. This is the server log:

```
<5/07/2014 10:36:36 AM COT> <Debug> <SecuritySSL> <BEA-000000> <Use JSSE SSL (default strength)> 
<5/07/2014 10:36:36 AM COT> <Debug> <SecuritySSL> <BEA-000000> <[Thread[[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '1' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)',5,Pooled Threads]]weblogic.security.SSL.jsseadapter: SSLCONTEXT: Set weblogic.security.utils.SSLTruster to weblogic.security.utils.SSLTrustValidator@40c05e98.> 
<5/07/2014 10:36:36 AM COT> <Debug> <SecuritySSL> <BEA-000000> <[Thread[[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '1' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)',5,Pooled Threads]]weblogic.security.SSL.jsseadapter: SSLCONTEXT: Set weblogic.security.utils.SSLHostnameVerifier to weblogic.security.utils.SSLWLSHostnameVerifier@261be85a.> 
<5/07/2014 10:36:36 AM COT> <Debug> <SecuritySSL> <BEA-000000> <[Thread[[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '1' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)',5,Pooled Threads]]weblogic.security.SSL.jsseadapter: SSLCONTEXT: Set enforceConstraints level to 0.> 
<5/07/2014 10:36:36 AM COT> <Debug> <SecuritySSL> <BEA-000000> <SSLSetup: loading trusted CA certificates> 
<5/07/2014 10:36:36 AM COT> <Debug> <SecuritySSL> <BEA-000000> <[Thread[[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '1' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)',5,Pooled Threads]]weblogic.security.SSL.jsseadapter: SSLCONTEXT: addTrustedCA called.> 
<5/07/2014 10:36:36 AM COT> <Debug> <SecuritySSL> <BEA-000000> <[Thread[[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '1' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)',5,Pooled Threads]]weblogic.security.SSL.jsseadapter: SSLCONTEXT: addTrustedCA called.> 
<5/07/2014 10:36:36 AM COT> <Debug> <SecuritySSL> <BEA-000000> <[Thread[[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '1' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)',5,Pooled Threads]]weblogic.security.SSL.jsseadapter: SSLCONTEXT: addTrustedCA called.> 
<5/07/2014 10:36:36 AM COT> <Debug> <SecuritySSL> <BEA-000000> <[Thread[[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '1' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)',5,Pooled Threads]]weblogic.security.SSL.jsseadapter: SSLCONTEXT: addTrustedCA called.> 
<5/07/2014 10:36:36 AM COT> <Debug> <SecuritySSL> <BEA-000000> <[Thread[[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '1' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)',5,Pooled Threads]]weblogic.security.SSL.jsseadapter: SSLCONTEXT: addTrustedCA called.> 
<5/07/2014 10:36:36 AM COT> <Debug> <SecuritySSL> <BEA-000000> <[Thread[[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '1' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)',5,Pooled Threads]]weblogic.security.SSL.jsseadapter: SSLCONTEXT: addTrustedCA called.> 
<5/07/2014 10:36:36 AM COT> <Debug> <SecuritySSL> <BEA-000000> <[Thread[[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '1' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)',5,Pooled Threads]]weblogic.security.SSL.jsseadapter: SSLCONTEXT: Got SSLContext, protocol=TLS, provider=SunJSSE> 
<5/07/2014 10:36:36 AM COT> <Debug> <SecuritySSL> <BEA-000000> <[Thread[[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '1' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)',5,Pooled Threads]]weblogic.security.SSL.jsseadapter: SSLENGINE: SSLEngine.setEnabledCipherSuites(String[]): value=TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256,TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256,TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256,TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256,TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256,TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256,TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256,TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA,TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA,SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA,TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA,TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA,TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA,TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA,SSL_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA,TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA,TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA,SSL_DHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA,SSL_DHE_DSS_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA,SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_MD5,TLS_EMPTY_RENEGOTIATION_INFO_SCSV.> 
<5/07/2014 10:36:36 AM COT> <Debug> <SecuritySSL> <BEA-000000> <[Thread[[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '1' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)',5,Pooled Threads]]weblogic.security.SSL.jsseadapter: SSLENGINE: SSLEngine.setEnabledProtocols(String[]): value=SSLv2Hello,SSLv3,TLSv1,TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2.> 
<5/07/2014 10:36:36 AM COT> <Debug> <SecuritySSL> <BEA-000000> <[Thread[[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '1' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)',5,Pooled Threads]]weblogic.security.SSL.jsseadapter: SSLENGINE: SSLEngine.setEnableSessionCreation(boolean): value=true.> 
<5/07/2014 10:36:36 AM COT> <Debug> <SecuritySSL> <BEA-000000> <[Thread[[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '1' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)',5,Pooled Threads]]weblogic.security.SSL.jsseadapter: SSLENGINE: SSLEngine.setUseClientMode(boolean): value=true.> 
<5/07/2014 10:36:36 AM COT> <Debug> <SecuritySSL> <BEA-000000> <[Thread[[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '1' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)',5,Pooled Threads]]weblogic.security.SSL.jsseadapter: SSLENGINE: SSLEngine.setWantClientAuth(boolean): value=false.> 
<5/07/2014 10:36:36 AM COT> <Debug> <SecuritySSL> <BEA-000000> <[Thread[[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '1' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)',5,Pooled Threads]]weblogic.security.SSL.jsseadapter: SSLENGINE: SSLEngine.setNeedClientAuth(boolean): value=false.> 
<5/07/2014 10:36:36 AM COT> <Debug> <SecuritySSL> <BEA-000000> <[Thread[[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '1' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)',5,Pooled Threads]]weblogic.security.SSL.jsseadapter: SSLENGINE: SSLEngine.setNeedClientAuth(boolean): value=false.> 
<5/07/2014 10:36:36 AM COT> <Debug> <SecuritySSL> <BEA-000000> <[Thread[[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '1' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)',5,Pooled Threads]]weblogic.security.SSL.jsseadapter: SSLENGINE: SSLEngine.setUseClientMode(boolean): value=true.> 
<5/07/2014 10:36:36 AM COT> <Debug> <SecuritySSL> <BEA-000000> <[Thread[[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '1' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)',5,Pooled Threads]]weblogic.security.SSL.jsseadapter: SSLENGINE: SSLEngine.setUseClientMode(boolean): value=true.> 
<5/07/2014 10:36:37 AM COT> <Debug> <SecuritySSL> <BEA-000000> <[Thread[[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '1' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)',5,Pooled Threads]]weblogic.security.SSL.jsseadapter: SSLENGINE: SSLEngine.wrap(ByteBuffer,ByteBuffer) called: result=Status = OK HandshakeStatus = NEED_UNWRAP
bytesConsumed = 0 bytesProduced = 145.> 
<5/07/2014 10:36:37 AM COT> <Debug> <SecuritySSL> <BEA-000000> <[Thread[[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '1' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)',5,Pooled Threads]]weblogic.security.SSL.jsseadapter: SSLENGINE: SSLEngine.unwrap(ByteBuffer,ByteBuffer[]) called: result=Status = BUFFER_UNDERFLOW HandshakeStatus = NEED_UNWRAP
bytesConsumed = 0 bytesProduced = 0.> 
<5/07/2014 10:36:37 AM COT> <Debug> <SecuritySSL> <BEA-000000> <[Thread[[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '1' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)',5,Pooled Threads]]weblogic.security.SSL.jsseadapter: SSLENGINE: SSLEngine.unwrap(ByteBuffer,ByteBuffer[]) called: result=Status = OK HandshakeStatus = NEED_TASK
bytesConsumed = 86 bytesProduced = 0.> 
<5/07/2014 10:36:37 AM COT> <Debug> <SecuritySSL> <BEA-000000> <[Thread[[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '1' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)',5,Pooled Threads]]weblogic.security.SSL.jsseadapter: SSLENGINE: SSLEngine.unwrap(ByteBuffer,ByteBuffer[]) called: result=Status = BUFFER_UNDERFLOW HandshakeStatus = NEED_UNWRAP
bytesConsumed = 0 bytesProduced = 0.> 
<5/07/2014 10:36:37 AM COT> <Debug> <SecuritySSL> <BEA-000000> <[Thread[[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '1' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)',5,Pooled Threads]]weblogic.security.SSL.jsseadapter: SSLENGINE: SSLEngine.unwrap(ByteBuffer,ByteBuffer[]) called: result=Status = OK HandshakeStatus = NEED_TASK
bytesConsumed = 3223 bytesProduced = 0.> 
<5/07/2014 10:36:37 AM COT> <Debug> <SecuritySSL> <BEA-000000> <[Thread[[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '1' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)',5,Pooled Threads]]weblogic.security.SSL.jsseadapter: SSLENGINE: SSLEngine.unwrap(ByteBuffer,ByteBuffer[]) called: result=Status = OK HandshakeStatus = NEED_TASK
bytesConsumed = 9 bytesProduced = 0.> 
<5/07/2014 10:36:37 AM COT> <Debug> <SecuritySSL> <BEA-000000> <[Thread[[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '1' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)',5,Pooled Threads]]weblogic.security.SSL.jsseadapter: SSLENGINE: SSLEngine.wrap(ByteBuffer,ByteBuffer) called: result=Status = OK HandshakeStatus = NEED_WRAP
bytesConsumed = 0 bytesProduced = 267.> 
<5/07/2014 10:36:37 AM COT> <Debug> <SecuritySSL> <BEA-000000> <[Thread[[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '1' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)',5,Pooled Threads]]weblogic.security.SSL.jsseadapter: SSLENGINE: SSLEngine.wrap(ByteBuffer,ByteBuffer) called: result=Status = OK HandshakeStatus = NEED_WRAP
bytesConsumed = 0 bytesProduced = 6.> 
<5/07/2014 10:36:37 AM COT> <Debug> <SecuritySSL> <BEA-000000> <[Thread[[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '1' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)',5,Pooled Threads]]weblogic.security.SSL.jsseadapter: SSLENGINE: SSLEngine.wrap(ByteBuffer,ByteBuffer) called: result=Status = OK HandshakeStatus = NEED_UNWRAP
bytesConsumed = 0 bytesProduced = 53.> 
<5/07/2014 10:36:37 AM COT> <Debug> <SecuritySSL> <BEA-000000> <[Thread[[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '1' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)',5,Pooled Threads]]weblogic.security.SSL.jsseadapter: SSLENGINE: SSLEngine.unwrap(ByteBuffer,ByteBuffer[]) called: result=Status = BUFFER_UNDERFLOW HandshakeStatus = NEED_UNWRAP
bytesConsumed = 0 bytesProduced = 0.> 
<5/07/2014 10:36:37 AM COT> <Debug> <SecuritySSL> <BEA-000000> <[Thread[[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '1' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)',5,Pooled Threads]]weblogic.security.SSL.jsseadapter: SSLENGINE: SSLEngine.unwrap(ByteBuffer,ByteBuffer[]) called: result=Status = OK HandshakeStatus = NEED_UNWRAP
bytesConsumed = 6 bytesProduced = 0.> 
<5/07/2014 10:36:37 AM COT> <Debug> <SecuritySSL> <BEA-000000> <[Thread[[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '1' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)',5,Pooled Threads]]weblogic.security.SSL.jsseadapter: SSLENGINE: SSLEngine.unwrap(ByteBuffer,ByteBuffer[]) called: result=Status = OK HandshakeStatus = FINISHED
bytesConsumed = 53 bytesProduced = 0.> 
<5/07/2014 10:36:37 AM COT> <Debug> <SecuritySSL> <BEA-000000> <[Thread[[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '1' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)',5,Pooled Threads]]weblogic.security.SSL.jsseadapter: SSLENGINE: negotiatedCipherSuite: SSL_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA> 
<5/07/2014 10:36:37 AM COT> <Debug> <SecuritySSL> <BEA-000000> <[Thread[[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '1' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)',5,Pooled Threads]]weblogic.security.SSL.jsseadapter: SSLENGINE: SSLEngine.getNeedClientAuth(): false> 
<5/07/2014 10:36:37 AM COT> <Debug> <SecuritySSL> <BEA-000000> <[Thread[[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '1' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)',5,Pooled Threads]]weblogic.security.SSL.jsseadapter: SSLENGINE: Peer certificate chain: [Ljava.security.cert.X509Certificate;@6a313eac> 
<5/07/2014 10:36:37 AM COT> <Debug> <SecuritySSL> <BEA-000000> <[Thread[[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '1' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)',5,Pooled Threads]]weblogic.security.SSL.jsseadapter: SSLENGINE: weblogic.security.utils.SSLTrustValidator.isPeerCertsRequired(): false> 
<5/07/2014 10:36:37 AM COT> <Debug> <SecuritySSL> <BEA-000000> <validationCallback: validateErr = 0> 
<5/07/2014 10:36:37 AM COT> <Debug> <SecuritySSL> <BEA-000000> <weblogic user specified trustmanager validation status 0> 
<5/07/2014 10:36:37 AM COT> <Debug> <SecuritySSL> <BEA-000000> <SSLTrustValidator returns: 0> 
<5/07/2014 10:36:37 AM COT> <Debug> <SecuritySSL> <BEA-000000> <[Thread[[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '1' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)',5,Pooled Threads]]weblogic.security.SSL.jsseadapter: SSLENGINE: No trust failure, validateErr=0.> 
<5/07/2014 10:36:37 AM COT> <Debug> <SecuritySSL> <BEA-000000> <Performing hostname validation checks: caar-test.crm.us1.oraclecloud.com> 
<5/07/2014 10:36:37 AM COT> <Debug> <SecuritySSL> <BEA-000000> <[Thread[[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '1' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)',5,Pooled Threads]]weblogic.security.SSL.jsseadapter: SSLENGINE: Successfully completed post-handshake processing.> 
<5/07/2014 10:36:37 AM COT> <Debug> <SecuritySSL> <BEA-000000> <[Thread[[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '1' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)',5,Pooled Threads]]weblogic.security.SSL.jsseadapter: SSLENGINE: SSLEngine.wrap(ByteBuffer,ByteBuffer) called: result=Status = OK HandshakeStatus = NOT_HANDSHAKING
bytesConsumed = 349 bytesProduced = 389.> 
<5/07/2014 10:36:37 AM COT> <Debug> <SecuritySSL> <BEA-000000> <[Thread[[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '1' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)',5,Pooled Threads]]weblogic.security.SSL.jsseadapter: SSLENGINE: SSLEngine.wrap(ByteBuffer,ByteBuffer) called: result=Status = OK HandshakeStatus = NOT_HANDSHAKING
bytesConsumed = 1606 bytesProduced = 1645.> 
<5/07/2014 10:36:38 AM COT> <Debug> <SecuritySSL> <BEA-000000> <[Thread[[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '1' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)',5,Pooled Threads]]weblogic.security.SSL.jsseadapter: SSLENGINE: SSLEngine.unwrap(ByteBuffer,ByteBuffer[]) called: result=Status = OK HandshakeStatus = NOT_HANDSHAKING
bytesConsumed = 1325 bytesProduced = 1291.> 
<5/07/2014 10:36:38 AM COT> <Debug> <SecuritySSL> <BEA-000000> <[Thread[[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '1' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)',5,Pooled Threads]]weblogic.security.SSL.jsseadapter: SSLENGINE: SSLEngine.unwrap(ByteBuffer,ByteBuffer[]) called: result=Status = OK HandshakeStatus = NOT_HANDSHAKING
bytesConsumed = 1245 bytesProduced = 1206.> 
<5/07/2014 10:36:38 AM COT> <Error> <HTTP> <WL-101020> <[ServletContext@822614083[app:mypackage_ServicioWeb_war_1.0-SNAPSHOT module:ServicioWeb-1.0-SNAPSHOT path:null spec-version:3.0]] Servlet failed with an Exception
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at weblogic.wsee.security.saml.SAMLTrustCredentialProvider.getCredentialFromRSTR(SAMLTrustCredentialProvider.java:494)
    at weblogic.wsee.security.saml.SAMLTrustCredentialProvider.createCredential(SAMLTrustCredentialProvider.java:443)
    at weblogic.wsee.security.saml.SAMLTrustCredentialProvider.getCredentialSTSCSS(SAMLTrustCredentialProvider.java:189)
    at weblogic.wsee.security.saml.SAMLTrustCredentialProvider.getCredential(SAMLTrustCredentialProvider.java:101)
    at weblogic.xml.crypto.wss.WrapperCredentialProvider.getCredential(WrapperCredentialProvider.java:55)
    at weblogic.xml.crypto.wss.SecurityBuilderImpl.getCredential(SecurityBuilderImpl.java:778)
    at weblogic.xml.crypto.wss.SecurityBuilderImpl.getSecurityToken(SecurityBuilderImpl.java:751)
    at weblogic.xml.crypto.wss.SecurityBuilderImpl.addSecurityToken(SecurityBuilderImpl.java:287)
    at weblogic.wsee.security.wss.plan.SecurityMessageArchitect.doProcessIdentity(SecurityMessageArchitect.java:924)
    at weblogic.wsee.security.wss.plan.SecurityMessageArchitect.processIdentity(SecurityMessageArchitect.java:890)
    at weblogic.wsee.security.wss.plan.SecurityMessageArchitect.constructMessage(SecurityMessageArchitect.java:185)
    at weblogic.wsee.security.wss.plan.SecurityMessageArchitect.buildWssMessage(SecurityMessageArchitect.java:138)
    at weblogic.wsee.security.wss.plan.SecurityMessageArchitect.buildWssMessage(SecurityMessageArchitect.java:121)
    at weblogic.wsee.security.wss.SecurityPolicyArchitect.processOutbound(SecurityPolicyArchitect.java:226)
    at weblogic.wsee.security.wss.SecurityPolicyArchitect.processMessagePolicy(SecurityPolicyArchitect.java:134)
    at weblogic.wsee.security.wss.SecurityPolicyConductor.processRequestOutbound(SecurityPolicyConductor.java:120)
    at weblogic.wsee.security.wss.SecurityPolicyConductor.processRequestOutbound(SecurityPolicyConductor.java:92)
    at weblogic.wsee.security.wssp.handlers.WssClientHandler.processOutbound(WssClientHandler.java:114)
    at weblogic.wsee.security.wssp.handlers.WssClientHandler.processRequest(WssClientHandler.java:66)
    at weblogic.wsee.security.wssp.handlers.WssHandler.handleRequest(WssHandler.java:113)
    at weblogic.wsee.jaxws.framework.jaxrpc.TubeFactory$JAXRPCTube.processRequest(TubeFactory.java:269)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.__doRun(Fiber.java:1136)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber._doRun(Fiber.java:1050)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.doRun(Fiber.java:1019)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.runSync(Fiber.java:877)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.client.Stub.process(Stub.java:464)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.client.sei.SEIStub.doProcess(SEIStub.java:174)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(SyncMethodHandler.java:108)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(SyncMethodHandler.java:91)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.client.sei.SEIStub.invoke(SEIStub.java:154)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy144.createOpportunity(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at weblogic.wsee.jaxws.spi.ClientInstanceInvocationHandler.invoke(ClientInstanceInvocationHandler.java:84)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy145.createOpportunity(Unknown Source)
    at mypackage.servicioweb.ConsumirOportunidad.processRequest(ConsumeService.java:74)
    at mypackage.servicioweb.ConsumeService.doGet(ConsumeService.java:99)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:844)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:280)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:254)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:136)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:341)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:238)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.wrapRun(WebAppServletContext.java:3363)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.run(WebAppServletContext.java:3333)
    at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
    at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:120)
    at weblogic.servlet.provider.WlsSubjectHandle.run(WlsSubjectHandle.java:57)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.doSecuredExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2220)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.securedExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2146)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.execute(WebAppServletContext.java:2124)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.run(ServletRequestImpl.java:1564)
    at weblogic.servlet.provider.ContainerSupportProviderImpl$WlsRequestExecutor.run(ContainerSupportProviderImpl.java:254)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:295)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:254)
```

I assume that weblogic is trying to consume the web
service using the policy "oracle/wss11_saml_token_with_message_protection_client_policy" instead of "oracle/wss11_username_token_with_message_protection_client_policy".

I have been able to consume the web service successfully using SoapUI, a standalone client and the same war application deployed in Apache Tomcat.

I want to keep the web service client logic as simple as possible, i.e. sending the username and password using basic authentication without using a mapping credential provider o saml.

Please let me know if you have any ideas or suggestions that can help me with this.